# what does .models mean in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am trying to import a class named 'Questions' from my models.py to admin.py
`from .models import Questions`
I don't understand why we have to use a period in '.models', what does it mean and what exactly is it pin pointing to?

I tried this combinations but it was no avail
`from models import Questions`
`from Model.models import Questions`

Comment: Normally, `.` is used to specify current directory, so if you write `from .models import SomeModelName` so it means import models from the current app(for Django) or current directory, and if you write `from some_app_name.models import SomeModel` so here you clearly specify from which app or folder you'd like to import models.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to relative import. you see their are 2 types of import statement:

1. Absolute import: they start from the root of the project. Like in Django where the manage.py is, that is the root. So your import statement can be written as

   `from {AppName}.models import Questions`
2. But here you are using relative path. Relative because you start from the current directory you are in and not the root. So in `.models` the `.` actually means current directory. You can not use `models` because there is no models in root directory.

For more in depth detail try this [Python imports](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-and-relative-imports-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

That's a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports). It means go back one level in the folder tree and import `models`.

This:

```
from .models import Questions
```

is the same as this:

```
from my_folder_containing_models.models import Questions
```